# WebAssembly: (f32.const nan:0x200000) means 0x7fa00000 or 0x7fe00000

Tags: c, floating-point, nan, webassembly

In C, `strtof("nan(0x200000)", nullptr)` represented as `0x7fe00000`. But in [WebAssembly spec interpreter tests](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/blob/master/test/core/conversions.wast):

```
(assert_return (invoke "f32.reinterpret_i32" (i32.const 0x7fa00000)) (f32.const nan:0x200000))
(assert_return (invoke "f32.reinterpret_i32" (i32.const 0xffa00000)) (f32.const -nan:0x200000))
```

So, in WebAssembly `nan(0x200000)` (or `nan:0x200000`) should be represented as `0x7fa00000`, or it's an error?

Why in C it is implemented differently?

Same question for `f64.const`.

Comment: C standard doesn't mandate a floating-point format, so it doesn't specify what an NaN should be, either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In C, strtof("nan(0x200000)", nullptr) represented as 0x7fe00000

This is not necessarily so. The behavior of the extra information for NaNs in C is implementation-defined.

The difference between the values 0x7fa00000 and 0x7fe00000 is that the former is a signaling NaN, while the latter is a quiet NaN. It looks like your C implementation chose to represent NaNs as quiet NaNs, so the most-significant bit of the significand is set, while the given payload is used for the remaining bits.

[WebAssembly](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/syntax/values.html#floating-point) lets you specify all significand bits including the most-significant one. You can create an "arithmetic NaN" (which has the most-significant bit set like a quiet NaN) by using a constant value of at least canon<sub>N</sub>, which is 0x400000 for 32-bit floating point. So you can create a representation of 0x7fe00000 by specifying a payload of 0x600000.